# How to avoid the on-screen keyboard from covering the EditText in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

whenever I click on the EditText, the screen readjusts and the edittext-view moves up. But this is not enough and the soft-keyboard still covers the view to not show what a user typing.

My layout is as follows:

A listview occupying 65% of screen height, followed by an editetxt view and a button

```
LISTVIEW


______________________________
EDITTEXT              |BUTTON 
______________________________
```

My activity has the following flag set  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Hi sorry for the old post but did you find a solution to this? i've read of adding a ScrollView to the form to allow scrolling but its not really working for me...

Comment: from what i've found i think its really a matter in Android to design around the issue

Comment: any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

adjustPan forces the soft keyboard to appear on top of your layout, blocking anything at the bottom.  You're going to want to use adjust resize instead, which will move up your EditText and Button, and shrink the ListView.  If, in landscape mode, the ListView is shrunk to the point of being unusable/pointless, consider using a fullscreen IME keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Read about something like that just recently. Is this what you are looking for?
http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/